# ffmpeg add video title / name as subtitle track

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

Is there an easy way to use ffmpeg to add the title of a video (mp4, mkv etc) as a custom subtitle track (lasting for the entire duration of the video)?

For example: "The adventures of foo.mp4" with a video duration of 100 seconds would get the subtitle "The adventures of foo.mp4" embedded from second 0-100 on a subtitle track?

Comment: Does "subtitle track" refer to softsubs? Or do you want hardsubs? What is your OS? This will require two commands and scripting can make it easier. VLC displays the file name or title metadata upon initial playback. It may be an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subtitle file: "The adventures of foo.vtt"

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:01:40.000
The adventures of foo
```

And run.

```
ffmpeg -i "The adventures of foo in.mkv" -i "The adventures of foo.vtt" -c copy -disposition:s:0 +default "The adventures of foo out.mkv"
```